# External files in SAS DI

Tags: sas-dis

*I am facing one concern when I executed Job in SAS DI to populate records in .dsv file then I am getting columns headers in multiple line instead in a single line, after column 257 external file is breaking the column values in next line so please help me out to get resolution of this *

I have deleted the external file and re-created with a new template and even tried to enhance the logical length in File Parameter of External file but still on same page as I am new in SAS DI so not able to find the solution.

Comment: What is a DSV file?  Is that something specify to SAS DI?

Comment: Bascially, .dsv is a file which has "|" delimiter indtesd "," in .csv file. is this making sense ?

Comment: Can you see the SAS log for the code that SAS DI decided to run to produce the pipe delimited file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have checked the code as well but seems SAS DI has limitation as can popup an error or warning message that 256 charecters in a single line is maximum lenght